# Please review my code

Tags: python, while-loop

Hi all I'm new to programming, and trying to understand while loop in Python.

I want to print the following

```
print 2
print 4
print 6
print 8
print 10
print "Goodbye!"
```

Here's what I wrote

```
x = 0
sum = x

while (sum != 10):
    x = x + 2
    print x
    sum = x + 2
    Print ('Good bye!')
```

Can any one please let me know where am I going wrong..

Comment: what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: don't capitalize `print`, and unindent that line so it doesn't print every time

Comment: there are much better ways to accomplish what you're trying to do, but those are the *problems* with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct fix:

```
x = 0
sum = x

while (sum <= 10):
    x = x + 2
    print x
    sum = x + 2
print ('Good bye!')  # <-- lower case, unindented
```

A shorter solution:

```
for x in range(2, 12, 2): # start at 2, increment by 2, up to but not including 12
    print x
print 'Good bye!'
```

Comment: There is no better time than the present!